# Closures - Variable Change After Use

Tags: javascript, closures

I am reading about closures on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and I can't understand something in the following code:

```
var test = 1;

function makeFunc() {
  var name = 'Mozilla';
  function displayName() {
    alert(name + ' ' + test);
  }
  return displayName;
}

//Create myFunction - test should still be set to 1 at this point
var myFunc = makeFunc();

test = 99999;

myFunc();
```

Why is `Mozilla 99999` being printed instead of `Mozilla 1` when the function was created while `test` was assigned `1`? Shouldn't primitives by value types? I also don't think assignment gets hoisted, just declaration, pretty lost.

Answer (score 4):

From [the article you linked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

> The reason is that functions in JavaScript form *closures*. A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared. This environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time the closure was created.

Here, `name` is closed-over: It's a local variable at the time that the function was created. Though it's not a perfect analogy, you can think of it like the `displayName` function has an internal pointer to the stack frame containing all the local variables that were around when you defined the function. If you were to pass in `name`, you could see it being kept.

```js
var test = 1;

function makeFunc(name) {
  function displayName() {
    alert(name + ' ' + test);
  }
  return displayName;
}

//Create myFunction - test should still be set to 1 at this point
var myFunc = makeFunc("one");
var myFunc2 = makeFunc("two");

test = 99999;

myFunc();   // combines closed-over name "one" with lexical scope test 99999
myFunc2();  // combines closed-over name "two" with lexical scope test 99999
```

Because `test` is in lexical scope, not a closed-over local variable, both `makeFunc` and `makeFunc2` manipulate the same value in global scope, meaning that resetting `test` can manipulate the output even after you've created the closures.

Answer (score 4):

A closure does not merely capture a snapshot of `test` when it is created, but captures the entire variable itself. This means that whenever the function `myFunc` is called, it will print whatever the value of `test` is when it was called, **not** the value of `test` when the closure was created.

In other words, inside the closure, `test` is still a variable, not a value. That means it can be changed and manipulated however you want, and anything that uses it will see those changes.

So for your code, as soon as you call `myFunc()` on the last line, the runtime will evaluate the expression `name + ' ' + test`, and since test is now `99999`, that's what you get.

Comment: To put it simple, closure contains not the variable's value, but the variable's **name** (that's what *lexical scope* means).

Answer (score 0):

`makeFunc` itself returns a function which is called only after the assignment `test = 9999;`. The variable `test` is accessed from the 'outer' context (by closure).

Answer (score 0):

This is because `test` is not updated when `makeFunc()` returns `displayName`.

Take a look at `name` which I removed from the method `makeFunc()` scope to the global scope. When `makeFunc()` executes, `name` will be updated to `Mozilla` from within the method scope. `makeFunc()` then returns the function `displayName()` without touching/updating `test`. `test` is only updated after the declaration of `var myFunc = displayName() // return value of makeFunc()`.

Changing the value of `test` after the declaration of `myFunc()` will then alter the `console.log()` value of `test`.

```js
var test = 1;
var name = "IE";

function makeFunc() {
  name = 'Mozilla';
  console.log("test inside makeFunc(): " + test);
  function displayName() {
    console.log(name + ' ' + test);
  }
  return displayName;
}

//Create myFunction - test should still be set to 1 at this point
console.log("test before myFunc declaration: " + test);
console.log("name before myFunc declaration: " + name);
var myFunc = makeFunc();
console.log("test after myFunc declaration: " + test);
console.log("name after myFunc declaration: " + name);

console.log("myFunc() before updating test");
myFunc();
test = 99999;
console.log("myFunc() after updating test");
myFunc();
```